# Unable to deploy Nextjs project using XAMPP

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, xampp

I wan to deploy my next projet to XAMPP.
I run `npm run build` it build successfully, how I use my project in **XAMPP** insted of `npm run start`

I add `"homepage": "http://localhost/safar/"` to `package.json` then run `npm run build` after that copy content of .next to safar folider.
I try `http://localhost/safar/` in chrom, I expected that my project works correctly but it shows all file of my project.[image][image]